# VS Code, extension for debugging HTML issue

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run some HTML code in Visual Studio Live Share, even when I press Run without Debugging, it always displays the following error: [the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55ge5.png)

> You don't have an extension for debugging HTML. Should we find a HTML extension in the Marketplace?
>
> <kbd>Find HTML extension</kbd>
> <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

This message also occurs when I try to add a new configuration too, and when I added a launch.json file nothing changed. I wondered what extensions are needed to resolve this problem - I am on Mac with Apple Silicon if that is relevant. Or if there are any other solutions.

Comment: Can HTML be debugged? It doesn't have logic that can be run. My guess is that you've accidentally set a breakpoint somewhere in an HTML file. Try clearing them out if there are any.

Comment: Open your HTML files with a browser...

Answer (score 0):

The VS Code debugger is for debugging programming languages. HTML (without any JS) is markup. If you want to test a HTML document, try the [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) or [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extensions <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with those extensions)</sub></sup>.